# SparkSession.getOrCreate() failing to return previously configured session, job fails

Tags: multithreading, scala, apache-spark, concurrency

We are running Spark 2.1.0 in Scala in a cluster.  We invoke jobs through the REST API, here is a sample Java command line generated by that client and invoked:

`"/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0/bin/java" "-cp" "/opt/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/:/opt/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/*" "-Xmx3072M" "-Dspark.jobNumber=162740893" "-Dspark.submit.deployMode=cluster" "-Dspark.master=spark://clusterhost.foobar.com:7077" "-Dspark.executor.memory=12g" "-DjobNumber=162740893" "-Dspark.driver.memory=3g" "-Dspark.app.name=foobar-loader-162740893" "-Dspark.eventLog.dir=/opt/spark/events" "-Dspark.jars=/opt/spark/foobar-1.0.jar" "-Dspark.eventLog.enabled=false" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m" "org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper" "spark://Worker@10.10.10.241:44745" "/opt/spark/foobar-1.0.jar" "com.foobar.Loader" "aaa,bob,ccc"`

We have a main `com.foobar.Loader` class (referenced in the command line above) and it creates a `SparkSession` like this:

```
object Loader {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkConf = // build configuration from properties files etc
    val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.config(sparkConf).getOrCreate()
    val rows:Dataset[Row] = // get rows
    val transformed = WorkerPart6(rows) // implicitly invokes WorkerPart6.apply()
    // do something with "transformed"
  }
}
```

We have about 20 Scala classes (such as `WorkerPart6`) that each do a piece of the work that are all invoked later, these are Scala singletons ("object") and in their `apply()` method, the first thing they do is get a `SparkSession` like this:

```
object WorkerPart6 {
  def apply(rows: Dataset[Row]) = {
    rows.rdd.map { case row => 
      transform(row)
    }.toDS
  }
  // ...
  def transform(row: Row) = {
    val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate() // exception occurs here
    // additional processing on row
  }
}
```

This is a simplification of the code but hopefully is demonstrative.

So the idea is that the job kicks off, the main class creates a properly configured SparkSession; and then all of the workers can just "`getOrCreate`" that session and pick up a properly configured session and do their work.  This allows the workers to not have to worry about how the session is configured to keep all of the classes independent and decoupled.

However when run in the cluster, this is blowing up with the following stack:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 113.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 113.0 (TID 451, 10.10.10.241, executor 0): org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:379)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2313)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:868)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:860)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:860)
    at com.foobar.WorkerPart6$.transform(WorkerPart6.scala:206)
    at com.foobar.WorkerPart6$$anonfun$2.apply(WorkerPart6.scala:44)
    at com.foobar.WorkerPart6$$anonfun$2.apply(WorkerPart6.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:462)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The problem is that this worker's `SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()` is being called before the main loader's, and so without the configuration, there is no master URL or other required parameters. The parameter it's complaining about missing is `"-Dspark.master=spark://clusterhost.foobar.com:7077"` from the command line.

We use this pattern everywhere throughout the code, getting a session with `getOrCreate` when needed, in dozens of places, and have run and tested hundreds of runs without a problem. It is only after recent changes to WorkerPart6 that this problem started to occur.

The curious thing is that `WorkerPart6`'s apply method is being called in a separate thread and the stack does not include our main loader class at all.  So I guess this is some Spark magic where it is creating worker threads and somehow initializing them with the classes that it will need. It looks like Spark figures out what instances and maybe what anonymous functions it needs and farms them out to separate threads?

How can I figure out how or why it is initializing these classes?  Is this usage pattern not a good idea? We do not necessarily need to obtain the `SparkSession` in the apply method; we could make these classes regular classes so their instantiation can be independent of the call for them to do their work.

Or, more generally, what are best practices for sharing a `SparkSession` across many worker classes without knowing the order in which they'll be created or threads they will be on?  I thought that is what the purpose of this `getOrCreate` method is but I must be misunderstanding that.

EDIT: I worked around the problem by creating a session in the worker's `apply` method with `SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()`, and then passing that session to all other methods in the class, rather than have each method call `SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()`.  This fixes this error but leaves me with the questions of 1) why does this fix it and what was the original problem, 2) how does Spark decide which functions will run on their own thread, and 3) does my fix cause my class to run with less concurrency or parallelism sort of like just adding `synchronized` blocks everywhere?

Comment: This is perhaps more of a code review answer than an explanation of why you're having this issue. But my feeling is a SparkSesssion should probably be created once, in one place, and passed around as a constructor or method argument to all of the other places it is used. This has the added benefit of decreasing tight coupling and making the code much more easily testable. But without knowning a lot more about how your code is structured and why you're using a SparkSession in so many places and from different threads, it's hard to say if this is the best path for sure.

Comment: If Spark is going to instantiate the different worker classes in an unknown order, how would you know in which class to create the session?

Comment: In your main class. Whatever you are passing to `spark-submit` or similar when you run the job. That's what is guaranteed to have the correct config set up and what can then instantiate whatever other classes you want. Note also that you should not be accessing the spark session / context at all from *within* spark tasks. Only in the driver.

Comment: I believe I'm doing exactly what you suggest but it is not working, I edited the post to make that more clear.

Comment: I meant to pass the spark session to the workers explicitly. Make the apply method take a SparkSession as a parameter instead of calling `SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()` once more. But again, that was more addressing the "best practice" / style portion of your question. I don't know why it's not working. Would probably need to see more of File14LocationLoad.scala to know.

Comment: If best practice were to create the session once and pass it around there would be no reason for a getOrCreate() API call, because there would be no "get".

Comment: @UncleLongHair I have had a similar error before when creating (for the first time) the `SparkSession` inside the main. Try moving the `sparkConf` and `SparkSession` outside the main but still inside the `Loader` object and see if it works.